# Add to an array nested within associative array javascript

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, associative-array

If I have an array that looks like

{X:{A,B,C},Y:{A,B,C}}

Where all the letters are variables

How would I add variable D to the array for the X variable key?
How would I add key Z variable to have the value of an array containing the A variable?

The equivalent of what I'm trying to do in php would just be

$array[x][] = d;

$array[z] = array(a,b);

Comment: array.x.d = something

Comment: Do you mean `{X: [A,B,C],...`?

Comment: `If I have an array that looks like` then you don't have anything that is valid javascript

Comment: @ James and @Jaromanda I think its pretty clear what I'm asking here. If you don't have anything useful to say please don't comment.

Comment: no. it isn't *pretty clear* at all - you've started off with a premise that is invalid javasvcript, so how can you proceed at all?

Comment: @Jaromanda it is. please stop commenting.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that comment. Is it because your javascript is invalid to begin with?

Comment: Note: {x: 1, y: 2 } is an object.
[1, 2] is an array.  We don't understand your question and are trying to help.

Comment: @user3609115 I'll add one more voice to the chorus — As it is, it's not clear what you want. Just edit your question and make it so arrays are delimited by `[]` and objects are delimited by `{}`.

Comment: One of JavaScript biggest problems is it seems like other languages, but isn't.  Please let me know if the answer helped.

Answer (score 0):

You can access a multidimensional array like this:

```
var a = 1, b = 2, c = 3, d = 4;
var ary = [[a,b,c],[a,b,c]];
console.log(ary); //[[1,2,3],[1,2,3]];

ary[0].push(d);  //add d to first array;
console.log(ary); //[[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3]];
```

You can also create an object to act like a lookup table.

```
var obj = {
  x: [a, b, c],
  y: [a, b, c]
}
console.log(obj); //{x: [1,2,3], y: [1,2,3]};

obj.x.push(d); //add d to array at x
console.log(obj); //{x: [1,2,3, 4], y: [1,2,3]};

obj.z = [d]; // add new key z with new array [d]
console.log(obj); //{x: [1,2,3, 4], y: [1,2,3], z: [4]};
```